# RMAN Duplicate with new SID / Path

Tags: oracle, restore, rman

We are running Oracle 12c SE.   I need to duplicate an instance from the RMAN backups.  However, this instance will be on a different server, with a different SID.   And, the pathnames have the SID in them:   /u01/<ORACLE_SID>/data_tbs, as such.

Not 100% sure how to do this, was hoping someone can give me some steps.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

Example:

```
run
{
  set newname for datafile 1 to '/u01/NEW_PATH/system_tbs';
  set newname for datafile 2 to '/u01/NEW_PATH/undo_tbs';
  set newname for datafile 3 to '/u01/NEW_PATH/sysaux_tbs';
  set newname for datafile 4 to '/u01/NEW_PATH/users_tbs';
  ...
  set newname for tempfile 1 to '/u01/NEW_PATH/temp_tbs';
  ...
  duplicate target database to NEW_DB
  logfile
    group 1 ('/u01/NEW_PATH/redo01.log') size 1G,
    group 2 ('/u01/NEW_PATH/redo02.log') size 1G,
    group 3 ('/u01/NEW_PATH/redo03.log') size 1G
  ;
}
```

Option 2:

[DB_FILE_NAME_CONVERT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-E8B4E0EA-B073-4349-9EA9-E053F499FB9E.htm#REFRN10038)

[LOG_FILE_NAME_CONVERT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-3D5894EF-C33D-4687-978F-F640174F6FCC.htm#REFRN10098)

On the new instance, set the parameters as required before starting the duplicate:

```
alter system set db_file_name_convert='/u01/OLD_PATH/', '/u01/NEW_PATH/' scope=spfile;
alter system set log_file_name_convert='/u01/OLD_PATH/', '/u01/NEW_PATH/' scope=spfile;
```

And restart the instance. You can skip all the above parts from duplicate command:

```
duplicate target database to NEW_DB;
```

Above needs to be done only once, these parameters can be set in advance in the SPFILE if you plan to do additional duplicates in the future.

Comment: Thank you   Seems like Option #2 is a more straightforward was of doing this.   One question:   I also need to change the SID, aside from setting the environment value, is there anything else needed?

Comment: Just use the `ORACLE_SID` environment variable and `instance_name`, `db_unique_name`, `db_name` SPFILE parameters you need in the new environment, and RMAN will handle the rest.

Comment: Ok, and one last thing:  Since the DB files are located on different mount points, would I issue one of the above commands for each mountpoint?  /u01, /u02, /u03, etc.....

Answer (score 0):

if the files can reside in one mountpoint or asm diskgroup on the new server, you can set db_create_file_dest in the spfile / pfile and all is fine.
no need for set newname or db_file_name_convert.

example: target server db files shoud be under /u02/data/
set db_create_file_dest to /u02/data/

after dulicate you will find all datafiles unter: /u02/data/newsid/datafile/